# PHPunit not seeing the text

Tags: laravel, phpunit

The text on the rendered page is:  Build a ***new*** squad

PHPUnit works with

```
->see('Build a');
```

but not

```
->see('Build a new squad');
```

something to do with the formatting?

```
Build a <strong><i>new</i></strong> squad
```

The text is in being output in the phpunit xml report as above.

Is there a switch or a flag that I need to use?

Comment: If you change it to `->see('Build a <strong><i>new</i></strong> squad')` does it see the text then? PHPUnit is likely just reading what it actually shows on the html and not actually rendering it.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, see function just check the raw html content. You can use `strip_tags($text, '<strong><i>')` with the response content, and maybe make a particular assertion. But `->see('Build a <strong><i>new</i></strong> squad')` is the correct way to test.